# Word Interop: can't group shapes

Tags: c#, word-interop

I create 2 shapes (textbox), then i want to grop it. Shapes are selected but not grouped. I have no idea how to do this...

Here is my code

```
        Word.Application wordapp = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document doc = wordapp.Documents.Add();
        wordapp.Visible = true;

        Word.Shape shNum1 = doc.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 10, 10);
        shNum1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "123";
        Word.Shape shNum2 = doc.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 150, 150, 10, 10);
        shNum2.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "321";

        doc.Shapes.SelectAll();
        wordapp.Selection.ShapeRange.Group();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.